# LPAD/RPAD: Align column

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I would like to align my column 'Gesamt':

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID AS ID, 
       vorname AS Vorname, 
       nachname AS Nachname, 
       CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(Betrag), 2), 0), LPAD('Euro', 4, ' ')) AS Gesamt  
FROM kunde k  
LEFT JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID  
GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

**Output:**

```
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+
| ID | Vorname | Nachname  | Gesamt      |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | Homer   | Simpson   | 20.95Euro   |
|  2 | Doug    | Heffernan | 120.50Euro  |
|  3 | Dexter  | Morgan    | 350.30Euro  |
|  4 | Sheldon | Cooper    | 1500.00Euro |
|  5 | Maurice | Moss      | 0.00Euro    |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

**So my desired output looks like:**

```
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
| ID | Vorname | Nachname  | Gesamt       |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Homer   | Simpson   |   20.95 Euro |
|  2 | Doug    | Heffernan |  120.50 Euro |
|  3 | Dexter  | Morgan    |  350.30 Euro |
|  4 | Sheldon | Cooper    | 1500.00 Euro |
|  5 | Maurice | Moss      |    0.00 Euro |
+----+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

How can I align it correctly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give SQL fiddle?

Comment: Quick idea, wrap your existing concat with `LPAD(Concat....., 12, ' ') as Gesamt` and change the `Euro` LPAD parameter from 4 to 5

Comment: This isn't an SQL (backend db) problem, this is a display problem.  That is, you should be doing this in whatever is displaying the results, not in SQL.  Do you know **for sure** that all of those amounts are in Euros?  It's also not amenable to internationalization...

Comment: Why not `asterisk (*)` instead of trailing space because space is ignored in mySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify the concat by concatenating `'<space>Euro'` instead of `LPAD('Euro',4,' ')` and add a LPAD in the whole concat to make it shift right (you can decide based on your data how many characters are needed in order to align):

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID AS ID, 
       vorname AS Vorname, 
       nachname AS Nachname, 
       LPAD(
         CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(Betrag), 2), 0), ' Euro')
       , 13, ' ') AS Gesamt  
FROM kunde k  
LEFT JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID  
GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `LPAD()`, you need it to work on the whole result, not only on `Euro` :

```
SELECT 
    k.KUNDENID AS ID, 
    vorname AS Vorname, 
    nachname AS Nachname, 
    LPAD(CONCAT(IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(Betrag), 2), 0), ' Euro'), 15) AS Gesamt  
FROM kunde k  
LEFT JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID  
GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

**Result:**

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+
| ID | Vorname | Nachname  | Gesamt          |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+
|  1 | Homer   | Simpson   |      20.95 Euro |
|  2 | Doug    | Heffernan |     120.50 Euro |
|  3 | Dexter  | Morgan    |     350.30 Euro |
|  4 | Sheldon | Cooper    |    1500.00 Euro |
|  5 | Maurice | Moss      |       0.00 Euro |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I really liked the previous answer it was very well documented (helpful images). It was a bit of an overkill for this particular problem but overall...really nice answer. ;)

Comment: @georstef Thanks... I was nicely writing my answer when I realized I simply used a tank to killed an ant x)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `asterisk (*)` instead of space because mySQL looks like is ignoring space in `LPAD()` function.

```
SELECT k.KUNDENID AS ID, 
   vorname AS Vorname, 
   nachname AS Nachname, 
   CONCAT(LPAD(IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(Betrag), 2), 0),15,'*', ' Euro') AS Gesamt  
FROM kunde k  
LEFT JOIN verkauf v ON k.KUNDENID = v.KUNDENID  
GROUP BY k.KUNDENID;
```

See my <kbd>[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1d54/1)</kbd>